# Section of a coherent sheaf vanishing outside a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

I need some help in understanding an argument, probably basic, about coherent sheaves, which I've read in a paper, and as far as I understand can be described as follows:

> Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_S$-modules, where $S = \{z\in \mathbb C: |z|< 1\}$. Let $\sigma$ be a section of $\mathcal F$ over the whole of $S$. Suppose $\sigma$ is "null" $^{\ast}$ outside of $0\in S$. Then (because of the coherence of $\mathcal F$) the germ $\sigma_0$ of $\sigma$ at $0$ is a torsion element in $\mathcal F_0$.
>
> (${\ast}$) Here  "null", I guess, should mean that $\sigma_x = 0 \in \mathcal F_x$ for each $x \in S-0$, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is this assertion correct as it is stated, and why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the assertion is true.
The section $\sigma$ defines a morphism $\Sigma:\mathcal O\to \mathcal F$ sending $f$ to $f\sigma$.
If $\sigma_0\in \mathcal F_0$ were not a torsion element then the morphism $\Sigma_0:\mathcal O_0\to \mathcal F_0$ would be injective and thus for a suitably small open neighbourhood $U$  of $0$ the morphism $\Sigma\vert U:\mathcal O\vert U\to \mathcal F\vert U$ would be injective too (by coherence of  $\ker \Sigma)$.
Then $\Sigma_x:\mathcal O_x\to \mathcal F_x$ would be injective for all $x\in U$, which implies $\sigma_x\neq 0$ for all $x\in U$: contradiction.

Comment: Am I wrong or you are not using that $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent? At least, you are using it for saying that $\ker\Sigma$ is coherent, but this is a weaker condition, is it? I mean that maybe the hypotheses can be relaxed?

Comment: @Cla: It is true that I use the coherence of the kernel, but it would be very difficult and unnatural  to obtain that coherence without supposing $\mathcal F$ itself to be coherent. Of course $\mathcal O$ is coherent but its subsheaves  need not be: if you don't see that, ask a new question :-)

Comment: Thank you, I actually see that $\ker\Sigma$ is not always coherent even if $\mathcal{O}$ is. I was wondering if there was some hypotheses to put on $X$ such that this is true: my feeling is negative, but most of the time my feeling is not right and I learnt it's worth to ask :) Best.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgesElencwajg. I have just one doubt left: when you say that there exists a neighborhood $U$ where $\Sigma$ is injective, are you using the fact that the support of a coherent sheaf (here $\ker \Sigma$) is closed?

Comment: Dear peter: yes, exactly!  More generally (but this is not so useful) the support of an $\mathcal O$-module of finite type is closed.

Comment: Very good, thank you again for your neat explanation :)